# Yammer - How to post via api to activity stream? (php)

Tags: php, curl, yammer

I am able to "GET" the activity stream but not "POST" to it. It seems its a technical error.
This is the code which *works* for getting the activity stream:

```
function getActivityStream()
{
    $as=$this->request('https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/streams/activities.json');
    var_dump($as);
}

function request($url, $data = array())
{
    if (empty($this->oatoken)) $this->getAccessToken();
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->oatoken['token'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?' . http_build_query($data) );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    return json_decode($output);
}
```

ok so that works fine... 
the code below, returns a Yammer **"oops this page could not be found"** message:

```
function putActivityStream()
{
    $data=array('type'=>'text', 'text'=>'hello from api test call');
    $json=json_encode($data);
    $res=$this->post('streams/activites.json',$json);
}

function post($resource, $data)
{
    if (empty($this->oatoken)) $this->getAccessToken();
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->oatoken['token'];
    $headers[]='Content-Type: application/json';
    $url = 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/' . $resource;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

One of the examples from:
http://developer.yammer.com/api/streams.html

```
POST https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/streams/activities.json
Requests must be content-type: application/json.

{
  "type": "text",
  "text": "The build is broken."
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to kick yourself. You have a typo in your code. :)
Change:

```
$res=$this->post('streams/activites.json',$json);
```

to

```
$res=$this->post('streams/activities.json',$json);
```

Simples.